# mod_rewrite redirect non-numeric IDs only when a directory isn't found?

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite to redirect on URLs like: mysite.com/123

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /n/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This works only for numeric IDs.

How do I make it work for non-numeric IDs while I preventing the redirect from happening when a subdirectory is found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the rewrite rules to this: This should work for both numeric as well as non-numeric IDs preventing the redirect from happening when a subdirectory is found.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w\d]+)$ /n/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```